# Laravel Api Postman Upload Image Return Null

Tags: laravel, api, postman

```
$files = $request->file('images'); // return {}

$_FILES['images']; // return {"name":"sample-passport.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"D:\\xampp\\tmp\\php4AD9.tmp","error":0,"size":264295}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to remove the `Content-Type` header? According to this [Github issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/191), it seems to be a problem.

---

So, I set up a new Laravel installation to test this out and it's working fine on my side. Of course, there's no authorisation whatsoever but this shouldn't impact the result too much.

**routes/api.php**

```
Route::post('/profile/upload_image', function (Request $request) {
    dd($request->file('image'));
});
```

**Postman configs**

[image: postman config]
[image: postman body]

Comment: I updated the answer with a piece of test code. This might help you to locate or resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks mate its working now i have problem on array loop on images

$files = $request->file('images'); // i have a single array image:[ tmp_name, size ,error ]

but im looping  each on [ tmp_name, size ,error ]
instead of images[ array(image) , array(image), array(image) ]
foreach ($files as $value) {  // problem array here 
}

Comment: I guess the problem here is that you're iterating over the values of a single file instead of the array of sent files: `$request->files('images')`. Note the plural form of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Your post input attribute type change file after upload you will get a response.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WUQ7.png)

Comment: Is this your current response
return {"name":"sample-passport.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"D:\\xampp\\tmp\\php4AD9.tmp","error":0,"size":264295}

Comment: $response->file('image') // return {}

$_FILES // return {"name":"sample-passport.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","tmp_name":"D:\\xampp\\tmp\\php4AD9.tmp","error":0,"size":264295}